# When using gatsby-source-filesystem's createRemoteFileNode can I access the publicURL of the downloaded file?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm working on plugin for Gatsby.

When using `createRemoteFileNode` to download a remote file (in my case an image) a File object is returned, however that object doesn't appear to have any information about where the file was downloaded to. This is added much later in the lifecycle by a resolver and can then be accessed on a File node using the `publicURL` field.

Is there any way to access the local location of the downloaded file from within JavaScript either from the File object returned by `createRemoteFileNode` or through another API. Ideally I want to know where the file was downloaded as soon as `createRemoteFileNode` returns.